# how to make clicking a button multiple times do different things

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make it so that each time I click the yes button the next square turns green and when I click no it goes back one square and turns red. I kind of have the idea of making each box a variable but I'm having trouble actually implementing it

Here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
div {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

div div {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
outline: 1px solid;
float: left;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
div div div {
  background-color: black;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}
button {
  margin:auto;
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Seven Stages of Misery </h1>
  <div>
      <div id = "b1"><h1>1</h1></div>
      <div id = "b2"><h1>2</h1></div>
      <div id = "b3"><h1>3</h1></div>
      <div><div></div></div>
      <div><div></div></div>
      <div id = "b4"><h1>4</h1></div>
      <div id = "b7"><h1>7</h1></div>
      <div id = "b6"><h1>6</h1></div>
      <div id = "b5"><h1>5</h1></div>
  </div>
<p id = "question">Did you do it right?</p>

  <button id="yes" type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('b1').style.background = 'green'">
Yes</button>

  <button id="no" type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('b1').style.background = 'red'">
No</button>
<script>
var b1 = 0;
var b2 = 0;
var b3 = 0;
var b4 = 0;
var b5 = 0;
var b6 = 0;
var b7 = 0;
var yes= document.getElementById('yes'), no = document.getElementById('no')
yes.onclick if (b1 = 0 || b1 = 2) {
  b1 = 1;
} else if (b2 = 0 || b2 = 2) {
  b2 = 1;
} else if (b3 = 0 || b4 = 2) {
  b3= 1;
} else if (b4 = 0 || b4 = 2) {
  b4= 1;
} else if (b5 = 0 || b5 = 2) {
  b5= 1;
} else if (b6 = 0 || b6 = 2) {
  b6= 1;
} else if (b7 = 0 || b7 = 2) {
  b7= 1;
};
no.onclick if (b7 = 1) {
  b7 = 2;
} else if (b6 = 1) {
  b6 = 2;
} else if (b5 = 1) {
  b5 = 2;
} else if (b4 = 1) {
  b4 = 2;
} else if (b3 = 1) {
  b3 = 2;
} else if (b2 = 1) {
  b2 = 2;
} else if (b1 = 1) {
  b1 = 2;
};
if (b1 = 0) {
  document.getElementById('b1').style.background = 'white';
} else if (b1 = 1) {
  document.getElementById('b1').style.background = 'green';
} else {
  document.getElementById('b1').style.background = 'red';
}

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is it ok if I give not very efficient version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it is not very nice coding and differs a lot from yours but it works for me very well. I hope that still helps!:

```
// Buttons
<button id="yes" type="button"
onclick="showProgress(1)">
Yes</button>

<button id="no" type="button"
onclick="showProgress(2)">
No</button>

// JavaScript function
<script>
function showProgress(answer)
{
    var currentDiv = 0;

    if (answer == 1)
    {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
            if (document.getElementById("b" + i).style.backgroundColor == "" || document.getElementById("b" + i).style.backgroundColor == "red")
            {
                currentDiv = i;
                break;
            }

        document.getElementById("b" + currentDiv).style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
    else
    {
        for (var i = 7; i >= 1; i--)
            if (document.getElementById("b" + i).style.backgroundColor == "green")
            {
                currentDiv = i;
                break;
            }

        document.getElementById("b" + currentDiv).style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This one is really good and much more efficient than my horrible if else if else statements. Thank you very much